# ¿Por que no se mantiene el dato seleccionado al pulsar buscar?

Tags: php, html, select

Tengo un buscador en el cual tengo un `select` llamado `personas`.

Quisiera mantener el dato del `select` cuando pulso en el botón "Buscar"

¿Por qué no se mantiene y siempre sale el número 2?

Supongo que sea por el código:

```
if($i==2){
   echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
```

No sé cómo se podría evitar y que aparezca el que previamente hayamos señalado.

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>COMPRAR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                    <h2>COMPRAR</h2>
                    <label for="personas"><b>Personas:</b></label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='personas'>";
                    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                        if($i==2){
                            echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"])){
                    //aqui va el codigo necesario...
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ese tipo de cosas se hacen a través de peticiones Ajax. En esencia se trata de esto: en el DOM (página actual) tienes tus dados y tu botón. Cuando presionas el botón se envía en background una petición al servidor que te busca los datos requeridos y te los devuelve (generalmente en un JSON) el cual luego lees en la función `done` de la petición Ajax, pudiendo actualizar el contenido del DOM sin tener que recargar páginas. [He aquí un ejemplo funcionando](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04), pruébalo pulsando en `Run-F9`. Sobre cómo hacer peticiones Ajax en SO hay varias preguntas...

Comment: En esta forma de proceder debe quedar claro que una cosa es la página actual, la que tiene el botón y otra cosa es el código que se ejecuta en el servidor (son dos archivos diferentes). Este último archivo es el que se indica en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax.

Comment: Entiendo tu explicación @A.Cedano pero me parece algo más completo programarlo en AJAX. ¿Se podría realizar únicamente en PHP?

Comment: ¿Completo o complejo? Usar Ajax es más completo y más complejo, claro que sí, pero no lo es tanto. Lo puedes hacer sólo con PHP, pero tendrás que recargar la página cada vez que quieras actualizar algo que implique traer algo del servidor...lo cual es más costoso a nivel de rendimiento y negativo en cuanto a la experiencia de usuario. Hoy día a la gente le gustan las páginas dinámicas que se actualizan *in situ*, sin tener que estar recargando, es justamente lo que hace Ajax: ocuparse de pedir los datos al servidor y ofrecértelos sin moverte de la página, todo de forma transparente.

Comment: ¿Pudiera ver la diferencia de la programación en PHP y Ajax? Para tener ambas versiones y echarlas un vistazo.

Comment: Para poder amoldarlo al código de mi proyecto.

Comment: En el enlace del primer comentario, de las líneas 40 a la 74 hay un ejemplo de petición Ajax completo (lanzada desde el click de un botón). Ojo, Ajax es código Javascript (usando aquí jQuery)... no estamos hablando de otro lenguaje, es Javascript/jQuery por lo general, o se puede hacer con Javascript puro.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71145/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Por qué no se mantiene y siempre sale el número 2?

La respuesta es porque siempre esta comparando si `$i` es igual a `2`, en lugar de validar si `$i` es igual al dato buscado.

### Solución:

Dado que los datos del `form` se envían por `POST` y que el `name` del `select` es `personas`, entonces es de esperarse que si se realizo una busqueda la variable `$_POST['personas']` ha de existir y tendrá el valor seleccionado por el usuario.

Tu código podría ser el siguiente:

```
<select name="personas">
<?php

// Si la variable no existe, establecemos el valor por defecto
if (!isset($_POST['personas'])) {
    $_POST['personas'] = 2;
}

for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {

    if ($i == $_POST['personas']) {
        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
} ?>
</select>
```